# The data from my firestore isn't displayed

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, builder

I tried to build an application, which shows the user some places on a google maps. The data for the places (location, name) should the app take from the firestore. The app already can display the maker in the google maps, but I also want some details in the bottom of the application in an Animated Builder, but it doesn't work. The problem is, that I can't get the name of the place with `specify['name']` in my `_restaurantList` function, but in the initMarker function it works. I think it has to do something with the `_restaurantList(specify)` and the return `_restaurantList(index)` but I don't know what the mistake is. I also tried to use specify instead of index in the `_restaurantList(index)`, but then I got an error. But I think I have to use `_restaurantList(specify)` in order to use `specify['name']` afterwards.

Does anyone know what my mistake is?

That's my code:

```
void initMarker(specify, specifyId) async {
    //   await Firebase.initializeApp();
    var markerIdVal = specifyId;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position:
          LatLng(specify['location'].latitude, specify['location'].longitude),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: specify['name'], snippet: 'Shop'),
    );
    print(specify['location'].latitude);
    nameTest = specify['name'];
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
      print(markerId.toString() + '__________________________');
    });
  }

  getMarkerData() async {
    Firestore.instance.collection('seller').getDocuments().then((myMockDoc) {
      if (myMockDoc.documents.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myMockDoc.documents.length; i++) {
          length = myMockDoc.documents.length;
          print(length);
          initMarker(
              myMockDoc.documents[i].data(), myMockDoc.documents[i].documentID);
        }
      }
    });
  }


 _restaurantList(specify) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _pageController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
        double value = 1;
        if (_pageController.position.haveDimensions) {
          //value = _pageController.page - index;
          value = (1 - (value.abs() * 0.3) + 0.06).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
        }
        return Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: Curves.easeInOut.transform(value) * 175.0,
            width: Curves.easeInOut.transform(value) * 350.0,
            child: widget,
          ),
        );
      },
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          null;
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0,
                  vertical: 20.0,
                ),
                height: 125.0,
                width: 275.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        offset: Offset(0.0, 4.0),
                        blurRadius: 10.0,
                      ),
                    ]),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      color: Colors.white),
                  child: Text(
                    specify['name'],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is in the Scaffold:

```
Positioned(
            bottom: 20.0,
            child: Container(
              height: 200.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: PageView.builder(
                controller: _pageController,
                itemCount: length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return _restaurantList(index);
                },
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: Please don't tell us what your application is not doing, instead show us what is the actual output. Is not clear to me if you are able fetch your data from Firebsae successfully (since you are already getting the location I think that you don't have any problem with fetching data form Firebase) or if you are just having issues to build your animated builder, did you tried with some mock/hardcoded data and it worked?

Comment: @Chris32 yes it worked hardcoded and I get the data from the firestore, but I can`t display the data in the animated builder.

Comment: Please have a look into the following [video](https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-slider-like-reflectly/) which can be helpful for you.